# C# DateTime.MinValue Field In PHP

Tags: c#, php, .net, php-5.3

In c# i can get the min value of the DateTime like this [DateTime.MinValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.minvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```cs
DateTime.MinValue
```

What i'm trying to do is the same but in PHP
Is there a way in php to get the min value of the 
`DateTime` In PHP

I tried with the [DateTime::setTimestamp](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimestamp.php)

```php
$dtms = new DateTime(); 
$dtms->setTimestamp(0);
```

The c# exemple gives me `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`

But php exemple `1970-Jan-01 00:00:00`

Comment: That's correct. That's the earliest date that PHP will automatically generate.

Comment: PHP is using Unix Time. The 'MinValue' of Unix Time is 1970-01-01.

Comment: Thank you a lot, now im sure :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's showing that date as that's the minimum timestamp for PHP it calculate all the dates from 1970-jan-01 00:00:00 if you want a date before that you will need to input negative number